# How to select rows from DataFrame based on subset inclusion?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column of sets and a column of numbers:

```
df
   ant                  cons
0  ("Q1A_3")            2
1  ("Q1A_2", "Q2A_4")   3
2  ("Q2A_5")            6
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to retrieve all the rows based on them being a subset of some provided set

```
selection = set(["Q1A_3","Q2A_4"])
```

such that the result of such a function/set of operations would look as follows:

```
df[df.func(selection)]
  ant                cons
0 ("Q1A_3")          2
1 ("Q1A_3" "Q2A__4") 3
```

Comment: df[df['ant'].str.contains(r"Q1A_3|Q2A_4")]

Answer (score 0):

Try two `contains`

```
subdf=df[df['ant'].str.contains("Q1A_3") & df['ant'].str.contains("Q2A_4")]
```